# CKEditor textarea extending out past box in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, ckeditor

In FF, Opera, IE the CKEditor is working and looks great. But in Chrome and Safari it is not sizing correctly, and is extending past the container that it is inside. I assume this is because Chrome and Safari are currently the most standards compliant. See the images below.

**Chrome**

[image]

**Opera**

[image]

I tried removing all of my CSS files to see if it was my css causing the issue, but that did not fix it either. Here is my call to CKEditor

```
//Make all textareas use the ckeditor
$('textarea.WYSIWYG').ckeditor({
    toolbar: [
        ['Styles', 'Format'],
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Link']
    ],
    height: 100,
    width: "225px",
    enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
    resize_enabled: false
});
```

Any ideas what could cause this?

**UPDATE**

Here is a VERY dumbed down version of the code still causing the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="library/javascript/global/JQuery.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/local_javascript/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/local_javascript/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/local_javascript/base.js"></script>

</head><body> 
<div id="outerWrapper"> 

    <table id="FAQTable"> 

        <tr id="editingRow">
            <td class="fixedWidth">
                <textarea class="WYSIWYG" id="FAQQuestionInput" rows="5" cols="1"></textarea>                   
            </td>
            <td class="fixedWidth">
                <textarea class="WYSIWYG" id="FAQAnswerInput" rows="5" cols="1"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>                    
   </table> 
</div>
```

And here is the new image

[image]

Comment: does the page validate ? can we see the hmtl ?

Comment: @mcgrailm: Yes its valid HTML5...Is my word good enough?

Comment: @mcgrailm: Well....there is 1 warning which looks to be associated with the CKEditor table inside my table. I will post it

Comment: @mcgrailm: I guess I could make my last row have colspan="3"??

Comment: @Metropolis that sounds like a good approach

Comment: Metropolis - have you had any success with this?? This is the only thread I've found referring to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This finally worked for me....added to config.js

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (evt) {
    //editor
    var editor = evt.editor;

    //webkit not redraw iframe correctly when editor's width is < 310px (300px iframe + 10px paddings)
    if (CKEDITOR.env.webkit && parseInt(editor.config.width) < 310) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('cke_contents_' + editor.name).firstChild;
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest so I am accepting it :). Does not force me to change all the browsers, and it works for the exact width that does not work. Thanks!

Comment: the "iframe" is no longer "firstChild".    `var iframe = document.getElementById('cke_contents_' + editor.name).getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];`   [link](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Minimum-Editor-Width-Safari#comment-48574)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, and finally resolved. It is a bad calculation made by the autogrow plugin that is executed after editor is created. Avoid that plugin to be executed with config.removePlugins='autogrow'; it works for Chrome, Safari, etc.

Comment: This one did not fix it for me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, **problem was in toolbar buttons**. You have to insert '/' to wrap buttons manually:

```
toolbar: [
   ['Source','-','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates'],
   ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
   ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
   ['Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'],
   ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks'],
   **'/'**,
   ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
   ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
   ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
   ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
   **'/'**,
   ['TextColor','BGColor'],
   ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize']
]
```

Comment: This was the problem for me too. I wanted my toolbar to automatically wrap.

Comment: In my case the bug is triggered by wrapping the editor in a `fieldset` element: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14261708/244826

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue with a css line, like this:

```
.cke_editor iframe {
max-width:600px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FIX!! ( brute force :D )
There is a iframe with in the textarea that forces prevents the editor form correct resizing.
In the Jquery Editor i forced the editor in submision by targeting iframes, and setting a width on it. this Fixed it for me and saved the day!

```
$("#txtNnode").ckeditor(
                {
                    width: "270px"
                },
                function(){
                    $("iframe").css("width", "260px");  
                }
            );
```

Comment: I was having this issue, not only in Chrome, but in IE as well. "Bruteforcing" a width, wider than the textarea, fixed it. CKeditor should really fix this.

Comment: Worked, but I hate to have to add this to all of my editors, and change the width in it depending on the width of the editor.

Answer (score 1):

**BIG EDIT**

My most sincere apologies I some how completely missed the fact that this was a Chrome issue and had been testing in FF thats why I wasn't showing the same problem; I'm a dumb A55.

So open and Chrome and what do you know the problem is there so the problem can be solved in one of two ways either you give it a width of 310px as shown bellow or you find a chorme specific fix for either the textarea or the toolbar CSS that deals with it I would also highly recommend submitting a bug report with ckeditor folks as they may be able to come up with a solution and put it out there.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('textarea.WYSIWYG').ckeditor({
         toolbar: [
             ['Styles', 'Format'],
             ['Bold', 'Italic', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Link']
         ],
         height: 100,
         width: "310px",
         enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
         resize_enabled: false
     });
 });
```

Comment: IMHO  there are much better ways to output web page content then to do it with tables

Comment: Because of the way this page is setup, and all of the ajax I am using, it would be tough to change the table to divs. I will try doing a colspan on the last column. Thanks again for your help mc!

Comment: @mcgrailm: Oh I completely agree, I use divs whenever possible, and I rarely use tables. But in this instance, it would be a pain in the arse to use divs. Plus I try not to be in divitus mode like some people :p.

Comment: Actually, it is not that issue.....I found an empty row in the bottom of my table that had 6 columns. I fixed that and the warning is gone on the validation. So that is not the issue. It is still displaying wrong.

Comment: @mcgrailm: Its on a private network.....But I believe that it has to have something to do with CKEditor and not my code. I think there either must be a setting to fix this, or there editor does not work when the width is reduced down to a certain size. I am trying to add some CSS to fix it, but they are using an iframe, so it may be hard to change anything on their end.

Comment: well no offense but you think its more likely that it is something in their code than yours ?

Comment: Yes, there are a ton of companies out there that do not care about standards compliance. Just go around the internet and try validating companies sites that you think should be on top of their game. You will start to see that a lot of companies are not keeping up. Also, I said that they may have an option to fix this, but they have a ton of options and I am not an expert with CKEditor, so I can not tell what setting may fix this.

Comment: There is no possible way this could be my code. I removed all CSS and this issue was still happening. You can see my code above that inserts the editor, and that is it. It gets added to a textarea, the rest is up to their code. We are talking about presentation, not PHP code. Its pretty cut and dry. Other than CSS, theres nothing my code could be doing to conflict.

Comment: You are using XHTML 1.0 STRICT. Think that may matter?

Comment: try using my method of targeting the ckeditor by using replace see if that fixes the problem ? I don't know how your ckeditor work with the jquery you provided

Comment: Can you test yours using HTML5 please? I just took practically everything out of the page except those things and its still happening

Comment: Did you install CKEditor in the root of your server?

Comment: It may also be a problem that I am using ssl?

Comment: i have a similar issue in chrome - but it regards to the text area being able to stretch manually (by the person browsing to the site) beyond his parent div? is there a way to limit it?  you know that 2 diagonal lines in the right bottom corner of the text area? that you can select with the mouse, and resize the text area - how can i limit it to stay in the bounds of it's parent? (it cause it's parent table to resize itself bheind the size of the table's parent DIV. although it is specified to be 100% in width.

Comment: Well I am glad I am not going crazy now. I thought you were testing in Safari, which also has the bug. I will try setting the width to 310.

Comment: The 310 width will not work since my space is not big enough for that. I will post a bug report on CKEditor. Thanks again mcgrailm!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to just add something like this to fix the width of the iframe once the editor is draw.

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function (event) {
    $(".fixCKwidth iframe").css({ width: "230px" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to this.

In my case, the ckeditor was in a table and by simply wrapping the editor in a div (still inside the table) and giving that div wrap a fixed with it solved it.

I tried changing the config file and so forth as mentioned above which seemed to do nothing to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple fixes above, but only the one from KeenLearner worked for me.  I had to wrap ckeditor in a div tag (still inside the td cell in the table), and fix the width of div tag like so:

```
<td><div style="width:642px;">
...
</div></td>
```

Thanks for the help, and I hope this helps someone else!