# CKEditor - Editor Width Overflows in Webkit Browsers

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I discovered that the toolbars [don't automatically wrap in WebKit browswers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5863324/244826) (Safari, Chrome). There is a [three year old bug](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/4232) reported for CKEditor 3, but it was closed. Maybe this is a regression?

I'm not setting a width in my configuration. I want the editor to expand to the available width automatically. The editor is inside a `div` element that has the `overflow: hidden;` style applied to it.

Here's my toolbar configuration:

```
config.toolbar = [
    {name:'clipboard', items:['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText',
            '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
    {name:'insert', items:['Link', 'Unlink', 'Image', 'Table', 'SpecialChar']},
    {name:'basic', items:['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike',
            '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList',
            '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock',
            '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent',
            '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
    {name:'styles', items:['Styles']},
    {name:'additional', items:['jQuerySpellChecker',
            '-', 'Source',
            '-', 'Maximize']}
];
```

Firefox:
[image: Toolbars wrap nicely]

Chrome (cuts off editor because of the container):
[image: Toolbars do not wrap]

I don't want to add hard breaks, because I use the same editor configuration at varying widths. How do I resolve this without using manual wrap "buttons"?

---

**UPDATE**

I use `fieldset` elements in my forms. I found that adding the `fieldset` is what triggers the layout issue. This code reproduces the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CKEditor</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            html {
                background-color: lightgray;
            }
            #content {
                margin: 0 auto;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 400px;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: white;
            }
            fieldset {
                margin: 0;
                border: 0 none;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <fieldset>
                <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1">&lt;p&gt;Foo foo!&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.0.1/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have [filed a bug report](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9947). I will accept an answer that provides a work-around for this bug.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update! This bug made me go mad. Never thought about a fieldset producing it.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed the `fieldset` either. I was just trying to create the most minimal way to reproduce the bug, and narrowed it down to the `fieldset` that way.

Comment: I have the same issue. Is it solved?

Comment: @JimmyKane - Yes. It's fixed in the latest release (4.0.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue. Neither on 4.0 nor on 4.0.1. I just copied your toolbar configuration + `{ resize_dir: 'both', resize_minWidth: 300, width: 500 }` to have better chance to observe if it works and this is the result:

[image]

**Update (11 Jan 2013)**

I created such a sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    <style>
        #content {
            width: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
            &lt;p&gt;Foo foo!&lt;/p&gt;
        </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                toolbar: // your toolbar
            } );
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And everything still works fine for me. I can change browser's width and toolbar is correctly resizing. So my guess is that some of your styles are breaking editor or you've got some non default CKEditor's settings that cause this.

Comment: I'm not setting a width in my configuration. I want the editor to expand to the available width automatically. The editor is inside a container `div` that has `overflow: hidden;`. I will add that information to my OP.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your case later. BTW. Assuming that this is reproducible, you should rather report this on http://dev.ckeditor.com. Such a difference between browsers definitely is a bug and in this case pretty important.

Comment: It appears that the `fieldset` element triggers the issue. I have added a simplified example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I added a bug report (http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9947). How long does it take for them to review accept it?

Comment: I've just marked it as confirmed and added it to milestone 4.0.2 (will be release in February).