# CKEditor 4 textarea replace - Toolbar increase the textarea width

Tags: ckeditor

I have a textarea that i replace to a CKEditor 4.1 instance using the "moono" skin.
The problem is that even when i configure the CKEditor instance to be 100% its toolbar 
increase my width depend on the its buttons amount.

From my research i understand that its happen because the in the "moono" skin 
"editor.css" file there is a "white-space:nowrap;" on all the element and this definition
is preventing the ".cke_toolbar" object to go into a new line even if are floating.

Notes:

1. The problem exist only if the parent object is a table object and this is why it can increase its width.
2. The default CKEditor width is 100% and when its say to the editor to get the parent pbject width so in my case i do not need to set a width to the editor (or i can set 100%) and it need to get the parent width.
3. For proving that the problem is from the toolbar you can cancel the javascript note lines in the SJFiddle project and see that the editor get the correct width.
4. In my case i can not use a new line on the toolbar because the textarea width is depend on the user.

Are there is a way to fix it using the CKEditor configuration or that i must edit
the "editor.css" and remove the "white-space:nowrap;" from the ".cke_toolbar" manually?
I do not like to do it manually because i do not like to fix it anytime i upgrate a CKEditor version.

jsfiddle.net/royshoa/9c2Xp/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor won't inherit width from textarea it replaced. You need to tell it explicitly its width.

In yout JSFiddle it's enough to add:

```
<script>CKEDITOR.config.width = 250;</script>
```

and it will be 250px wide.

Read more about setting configuration: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration

**Update**:

You've encountered this issue [CKEditor - Editor Width Overflows in Webkit Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261708/ckeditor-editor-width-overflows-in-webkit-browsers/14262501#14262501).

It's already reported http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9947 and the patch should be released with 4.0.2 so in about 2 weeks.

Comment: I am sorry but your answer is incorrect.
If you use width:'100%' it will take to parent object width
automatically. The default width value is 100% so i do not need to
set the width.

However I updated the JSFiddle project to be more understandable
and i found a detail - The problem exist when the parent object is a table object and this is why the white-space:nowrap increase it.

http://jsfiddle.net/royshoa/9c2Xp/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will wait to the next version.